# Is there a way to insert blank columns in output with google sheets query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

Consider the query run from sheet2

```
=query(Sheet!A7:A, "Select A,B,C where A='Order'")
```

but I want to put this in columns A,E,F in Sheet2.

I've found the workaround

```
=query(Sheet!A7:A, "Select A,X,Y,Z,B,C where A='Order'")
```

Where XYZ are blank columns from the end of the range.  This seems clunky.

So far searches in both the query syntax on Google docs, and google product forums have been unproductive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the empty columns as literals in the query - cannot really be empty though, must contain a space like this

```
=query(Sheet!A7:C, "Select A,' ',' ',' ',B,C where A='Order'")
```

Comment: So simple.  I'd tried using ,,, but that didn't work.

Comment: How do I add a formula in the blank column which takes input relative to the query results?

Comment: This gives the error: "unable to parse query function for query parameter 2: column_only_once ""()." =QUERY(Sheet1!A2:AD, "SELECT A,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,' ',' ',' ',' ',AB,' ',' ',AC,AD", 0)

Comment: I can see that ' ' doesn't produce the same result as a blank cell when another formula references the cell.

Answer (score 40):

I tried a version of [ttarchala's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43837180/2166885), just giving each blank column I wanted a different "signature", if you will:

`=query(Sheet!A7:C, "Select A,' ','  ','   ',B,C where A='Order'")`

Note the 1, 2, and 3 spaces in the quotes.

This worked - sort of. It gave me column A, then three blank columns, then B and C. However, it gave me a header row (which in my example I didn't want), and in the blank column headers I got:

`| " "() | "  "() | "   "() |`

Which was odd, but understandable. I hid the formula one row up and merged cells across A through C. Which left me with a nice blank cell. I took advantage of the fact that the output from query() can't be shown across merged cells.

This is of course a very specific solution - I had an empty row above my output that I could use and abuse for this purpose. But I thought I would mention anyway, just in case it gives a direction for better ideas.

**UPDATE**

Adding:

`... LABEL ' ' '', '  ' '', '   ' ''`

.. to the end of the query zeros out those odd headers that are added and removes the need for that extra row. This tells the query that the label for ' ' (one space) should be nothing, '  ' (two spaces) nothing, etc. This results in *no header row*.

Comment: What you can't do is have the query *skip* columns.  E.g. If you have columns  of other data that weren't produced by the query.  In that case, run the query on a separate tab, and copy into relevant columns with an array formula.

Answer (score 2):

If truly empty columns are needed then it is necessary to insert null values rather than spaces into those blank columns. This could be very important when creating data for a CSV file to import other systems, for example.

Instead of querying the data cells directly, curly brackets can be used to build a data set from the cells and then query on that. Let's build it up in steps.

You have two ranges that you want to insert three blank columns between. Those ranges can be written like this.

```
={Sheet!A7:A, Sheet!B7:C}
```

You can't just insert `""` between those ranges because that would only be one row of data and the number of rows must match the number of rows in your source data.

A little trick with the `LEFT` function can be used to make a blank cell for each row. The `LEFT` function can take 0 for the number of characters to return, which will return an empty string no matter what data it is given. Any range from the source data can be used. I'll use `A7:A`. When the whole thing is wrapped in `ARRAYFORMULA` it will be evaluated for every row. That can be repeated for each blank column needed. The data set with three empty columns looks like this.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({Sheet!A7:A, LEFT(Sheet!A7:A, 0), LEFT(Sheet!A7:A, 0), LEFT(Sheet!A7:A, 0), Sheet!B7:C})
```

There are some ways this could be shortened. One way is to make another data set inside a single `LEFT` function. The function can deal with arrays and will return multiple columns of empty strings. This is only a little bit shorter.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({Sheet!A7:A, LEFT({Sheet!A7:A, Sheet!A7:A, Sheet!A7:A}, 0), Sheet!B7:C})
```

If a large number of blank columns are needed then adding some character to each cell of the range, repeating it, then splitting it into columns on that character could be shorter. Changing the number of blank columns is as simple as changing the number of repeats. It does depend on choosing a character that would not be in the data, though, or it will break. Here's an an example with nine blank columns, which is no longer than with fewer blank columns.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({Sheet!A7:A, LEFT(SPLIT(REPT(Sheet!A7:A&"~",9),"~"), 0), Sheet!B7:C})
```

Since there are three columns of source data and three blank columns are needed, it can be shortened the most by referencing a larger range in the source. Empty strings will still be output for each column. Although this version is much shorter it depends on having source data with enough columns.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({Sheet!A7:A, LEFT(Sheet!A7:C, 0), Sheet!B7:C})
```

Now query that data set. Instead of referencing data by cell references, they are referenced in order as `Col1`, `Col2`, etc. Here's the whole thing together using the shortest version of referencing the data.

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({Sheet!A7:A, LEFT(Sheet!A7:C, 0), Sheet!B7:C}), "Select * where Col1='Order'", 0)
```

Comment: Instead of the trick with Left, you can also use `if(,,)`

Comment: @pa1nd I didn't have any luck using an if() function. Can you give a working example?

Answer (score 1):

If you need default values such as 0 in my case, you can do:

`=query(Sheet!A7:C, "Select A,0,1-1,2-2,B,C where A='Order'")`

Comment: Except that if you put anything in those cells, you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer I checked is indeed the best answer to my original question, I had a problem with it:

It required that the columns skipped be blank.  There was no ready way to use a single query to populate intermittent columns.  If I put anything in them, the query would break, and refuse to overwrite that cell.

Add to that query's other weaknesses:

- convoluted  syntax.
- different syntax between referencing internal and external spreadsheets
- Inability to use range names within the select statement
- brittle about changes in the source structure -- add a column and the query does NOT adjust.
- being dependent on *any* of the source fields made for frequent calculation of the entire result.

I ended up converting my query to 4 filter statements using the same criteria.

- For each column I wanted results from, I defined a named range.
- for each filter I defined my criteria and source in terms of named ranges.

E.g.

```
=filter(COcode,COcount > 0,isNumber(COcount))
=filter(COcount,COcount > 0,isNumber(COcount))
```

The double criteria on each filter is due to sheets having the idea that "foo" is > than 0.  Not something I find intuitively obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to get truly blank values in a column in a query result, instead of spaces, you can first build an array that has a column of blank values in it and then query that array instead of querying directly on the original data. The original data doesn't need to contain a column of blank values in order to achieve this. You can define such a column in a formula by using a combination of the ARRAYFORMULA and IFERROR functions.

The trick is that IFERROR can be used to force a blank value by defining a formula which divides by zero. Unless otherwise defined, the return value will be a blank.

```
=IFERROR(0/0)
```

This will only return a single cell value however, so for creating an entire column of blank values the ARRAYFORMULA function comes into play. The top zero in the above formula will have to be replaced by a range. To use the original posts data as an example, it would look like this.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(Sheet!A7:A/0))
```

Assuming that like with column A, in the source data the information in columns B and C start on row 7, an array could be built as follows.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({Sheet!A7:A,Sheet!B7:B,Sheet!C7:C,IFERROR(Sheet!A7:A/0),IFERROR(Sheet!A7:A/0),IFERROR(Sheet!A7:A/0)})
```

This array has the source data from columns A, B, and C in Col1, Col2, and Col3, and Col4, Col5, and Col6 consist of blank values. Now this array can be queried as follows to create the desired result as specified in the opening post.

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({Sheet!A7:A,Sheet!B7:B,Sheet!C7:C,IFERROR(Sheet!A7:A/0),IFERROR(Sheet!A7:A/0),IFERROR(Sheet!A7:A/0)}), "SELECT Col1,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col2,Col3 WHERE Col1='Order'")
```

Note that the order of the columns can be flexibly specified in the query.

I hope this will prove of help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

### [Sample File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T2RFDvOEJrpR5VHF7-fgbhu_OyYYkj72MBbnA-MeQQg/edit#gid=0)

[image]

I've managed to do the trick.

You may create a query input with some rare char:

```
=rept("", N)
```

Then you'll have a text like this:

```
select Col1, '', '', '', Col2
```

Substitute this char from the result:

```
=index(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY({A5:B12},D3),"",""))
```

where `D3` is your query.

---

Optional: use `label` to get rid of headers:

```
select Col1, '', '', '', Col2 label '' '', '' '', '' ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a named function called `ADDBLANKCOLUMNS` to allow me to append as many genuinely columns as I need to the table range. I can then use the `SELECT` statement to put them in the right places.

As I'm using the column headers to reference columns in my query statements (using an approach similar to the one [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57540/can-i-use-column-headers-in-a-query/167714#comment162560_167714)), the named function takes 3 arguments:

1. `range` - the range of the source data
2. `num_columns` - the number of blank columns to add
3. `header_prefix` the prefix to be used for the header column. If blank, there will be no header column and the column will be genuinely blank values, otherwise if you set it to "Blank", for example, it will name use the name "Blank1", "Blank2", "Blank3", etc. for each header column, but all the cells below the header will be blank.

The definition of the named function is:

```
={range, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(range), num_columns, LAMBDA(r, c, IF(OR(ISBLANK(header_prefix), r <> 1), , header_prefix & c)))}
```

So, given the following table in the range `A1:D3`:

| First name | Last name | Value | Conversion factor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Doe | 197 | 1.10 |
| Fred | Bloggs | 215 | 1.05 |

This can then be queried by wrapping the table range in a call to `ADDBLANKCOLUMNS`. Querying using the named function referenced [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57540/can-i-use-column-headers-in-a-query/167714#comment162560_167714), which I call `XQUERY`, in which case a query might look like:

```
=XQUERY(ADDBLANKCOLUMNS($A$1:$D$3, 2, "Blank"), "SELECT `First name`, `Last name`, `Blank1`, `Blank2`, `Value` * `Conversion factor` LABEL `Blank1` '', `Blank2` '', `Value` * `Conversion factor` 'Total'")
```

This results in the following output with the two blank columns inserted before the `Total` column:

| First name | Last name |  |  | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Doe |  |  | 216.7 |
| Fred | Bloggs |  |  | 225.75 |

## Using standard `QUERY`

If you're using the standard `QUERY` function, you can omit the third argument in the named function and define it simply as:

```
={range, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(range), num_columns, LAMBDA(r, c, ))}
```

You then need to use column numbers instead of letters (e.g. `Col1` instead of `A`), so the same result as above could be achieved using the following, where `Col5` and `Col6` are the two blank columns appended to the original range:

```
=QUERY(ADDBLANKCOLUMNS($A$1:$D$3, 2), "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col5, Col6, Col3 * Col4", 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another easy way to add truly empty columns to your query.

[example of adding empty columns to a query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBgaa.png)

```
=query(A:E;"SELECT Col1, 1/0, Col2, 2/0 label 1/0 'blank', 2/0 'blank'";1)
```

, where 1/0 and 2/0 (any number divided by zero) result in empty columns