# Concatenate two-dimensional arrays of different size (Google Sheets)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to concatenate 2 two-dimensional arrays of different size into a single array/table.
Both arrays are a result of a Query with a Group BY clause)

Example:

Array 1:

```
Account | Amount

Google 10,000

IBM 12,000
```

Array 2:

```
Account | Type | Amount

Yahoo Enterprise 8,000

Tesla Enterprise 14,000

Microsoft Enterprise 4,000
```

With a one-dimensional array, I would use:

```
={
{QUERY(A1:B1,"select A,B"),""}
;
QUERY(A2:F2,"select A,B,C")
}
```

OR

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( {
{A1:B1, SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 4), 2), 1, )}
;
A2:F2
})
```

But these don't seem to work for a two-dimensional array, I get the following error:
"Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 3. Actual: 1."
The empty cell substitution seems to only work for the 1st row, even when I combine it with ArrayFormula.

I'd appreciate suggestions on how to resolve this!
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could add a blank column when querying the first table, as shown on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46282317), so that both have the same amount of columns, and the concatenate both queries:

`={QUERY(D1:F4,"SELECT *");QUERY(A2:B3,"SELECT A,' ',B LABEL ' ' ''")}`

[image]

#### Note:

- In this example, the headers are provided by the second table.