# Appending the results of two queries in Google Sheets fails

Tags: join, multidimensional-array, append, google-sheets-formula

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HeldkN3k1H-WfyCusjOj4gocBtSeHkwKhDbNYDyYr5I/edit?usp=sharing

Appending the two queries in S2 does not work as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62340067/concatenate-two-dimensional-arrays-of-different-size-google-sheets?answertab=active#tab-top).

`={QUERY(C2:J, "SELECT D, I WHERE C <= date '"&TEXT(N1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0);QUERY(C2:J, "SELECT E, J WHERE C <= date '"&TEXT(N1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)}`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=arrayformula({QUERY(C2:J, "SELECT D, I WHERE D IS NOT NULL AND C <= date '"&TEXT(N1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0);QUERY(C2:J, "SELECT E, J WHERE D IS NOT NULL AND C <= date '"&TEXT(N1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)})
```

Answer (score 1):

There are blank rows after the first query and the second query starts at somewhere row 50000.

Add a wrapper query to exclude the blank rows.

```
=QUERY({QUERY(C2:J, "SELECT D, I WHERE C <= date '"&TEXT(N1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0);QUERY(C2:J, "SELECT E, J WHERE C <= date '"&TEXT(N1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)},"select * where Col1 is not null",0)
```

Answer (score 1):

use the proper way:

```
=QUERY({D:D, I:I, C:C; E:E, J:J, C:C}, 
 "select Col1,Col2 
  where Col2 matches '\d+' 
    and Col3 <= date '"&TEXT(N1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: This does work and I believe shall be more efficient than using "ARRAYFORMULA".
You  might have blank rows after the first set of results, so scroll down to see the others. To avoid that you can either use smg like " Col1 != '' " in your query or use @idfurw's solution (which is basically the same idea).